# macOS Monterey: VSCode - Kubernetes extension throws an error "Kubectl command failed: fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error runtime stack:"

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, macos-monterey

After upgrading to macOS Monterey, the **Kubernetes Extension(version v1.3.3) of VSCode (Version: 1.62.0)** is throwing the following error whenever it initialise. But the **Homebrew** installed **Kubectl** is still working fine in the terminal. Is anyone else facing this issue? Any possible solution would be of great help

`Kubectl command failed: fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error runtime stack: runtime.throw(0x2355d59, 0x21) /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:616 +0x81 fp=0x7ff7bfeff478 sp=0x7ff7bfeff458 pc=0x1028ff1 runtime.goenvs() /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_darwin.go:129 +0x83 fp=0x7ff7bfeff4a8 sp=0x7ff7bfeff478 pc=0x1026b73 runtime.schedinit() /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:501 +0xd6 fp=0x7ff7bfeff510 sp=0x7ff7bfeff4a8 pc=0x102b8e6 runtime.rt0_go(0x7ff7bfeff548, 0x5, 0x7ff7bfeff548, 0x0, 0x1000000, 0x5, 0x7ff7bfeff740, 0x7ff7bfeff76f, 0x7ff7bfeff776, 0x7ff7bfeff77b, ...) /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:252 +0x1f4 fp=0x7ff7bfeff518 sp=0x7ff7bfeff510 pc=0x1051e94`

Answer (score 2):

Solved this issue by manually changing the kubectl path in vscode's settings.json to the brew installed version

[image: vscode | settings.json]

**Another solution**: If you don't want to change the vscode's settings.json , just replace the **kubectl** binary in folder `/Users/<your_home_directory>/.vs-kubernetes/tools/kubectl` from the brew folder `/usr/local/Cellar/kubernetes-cli/<working_version>/bin`